# ASP NET MVC 4 Razor Views Precompilation taking an insane amount of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm asking this question only because I've tried every single solution proposed in all other questions related to slow razor compilation (both on SO and MSDN) and I'm completely lost and stuck.

### Context:

I have a ASP NET MVC 4 (.NET Framework 4.6.2) project with Razor view precompilation enabled in Release configuration in `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

IDE is Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.75.64347

Everything was working fine before completing a merge from a feature branch. After this merge, **when I compile the project in Release** configuration views take a painful (**40+ minutes**) amount of time to compile. While compiling, I can see in the Output window the usual code warnings slowly appearing (unused variables, unreachable code, etc...), so it doesn't seem like it's stuck on a single task, but it's simply very slowly compiling all the views.

**If I run the project in Debug**, views don't get precompiled so the project starts immediately, but every first load of every page takes again a painful amount of time (3+ minutes per page). It really seems Razor view compilation takes ages no matter how you invoke it.

### The problem

Razor View (.cshtml) compilation takes forever both while precompiling views and when compiling at runtime.

### What I tried:

Reading all the other questions here and other forums I tried:

1. Deleting .vs folder in project's solution
2. Cleaning the solution and restarting VS\computer
3. Changing port used by IIS Express
4. Deleting all files in "*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files*"
5. Deleting all files in "*C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files*"
6. Deleting all files in "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache"
7. Deleting bin and obj folders inside project directory
8. Running VS as administrator
9. Enabling and disabling Just My Code from VS settings
10. Clearing cache and sites from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"

### Additional info:

While "stuck" compiling views, my CPU (i7) stays at around 20-30%, with Visual Studio using 2-6%, so CPU it's definitely not the bottleneck here. Disk is an SSD. Ram is 16GB.

My colleagues, running the same codebase as mine, don't have any problem and compilation times are normal.

Any other project (or even the original branch of the same project, the one that caused the problem after merging) doesn't have the same problem.

The BuildAgent deploying the same application (in Release configuration, clearly) doesn't have any problem, so it's clearly something related to my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more troubleshooting, we were able to find a solution: I upgraded the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` from version `1` to version `2.0.1`.
**After this change, compile times went back to being acceptable** (~2\3 minutes for a complete Release build with views precompilation enabled).

I honestly have no idea how a nuget packages could cause a problem like this only on my workstation. I even uninstalled VS2019, deleted the workspace and reinstalled VS2022, but the problem still affected my workstation only.